# How to show ProgressDialog in a DialogFragment in AsyncTask

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-dialogfragment

My `ProgressDialog` is not showing - *It is defined in AsyncTask class **BackgroundDataLoad***.

**DialoguePopup Class -**

```
public class DialoguePopup extends DialogFragment {

public DialoguePopup newInstace() 
{
    DialoguePopup dialogFragment = new DialoguePopup();
    return dialogFragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    //view related code..

    //Calculation logic data load in background
    new BackgroundDataLoad().execute();
    return view;
}

class BackgroundDataLoad extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pDialog.setMessage("Calculating ...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
{
   //Data that can take 8 seconds to load is in background process
   return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
{
   super.onPostExecute(result);
   pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

**NOTE:**

After some more debug, I came to know that my ProgressDialog is showing below the DialogFragment but I want it on Top of DialogFragment.

The SO post [How can I open a ProgressDialog on top of a DialogFragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406223/how-can-i-open-a-progressdialog-on-top-of-a-dialogfragment?rq=1) mentions,

> Apparently thats a widely complained about subject with
>   ProgressDialog, I suggest you try a normal dialog, created with the
>   builder and whose layout (a custom one made by you) includes the
>   progress bar or loading or whatever you need. This should solve your
>   problem.

But I wonder if your application is using `ProgressDialog` throughout at different views then Is it the best way to do that with custom Builder?

It hinders the consistency of your application.  Moreover, that was the alternative way.

Comment: Where is declaration of pDialog ? Is it on activity ?

Comment: you are extend `DialogFragment` in `DialoguePopup`. there is no `Activity Context`

Comment: @Paritosh - See code above. It is declared in `onPreExecute()` method of `AsyncTask`.

Comment: @PRAKASHUBHADIYA - My `DialogFragment` is attached to an Activity so I am doing `getActivity()` to get the `context`. If it was not there, I should be getting null pointer exception on `getActivity()` call.

Comment: @VedPrakash I am asking about declaration, not definition. If it is declared on activity, we have to get its instance.

Comment: @Paritosh - I have defined it in the same class `DialoguePopup` and declared in the same class.

Answer (score 5):

@ My God

You just two step away.

1. `onCreateDialog()` as

   ```
   @Override
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
       dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       return dialog;
   }
   ```
2. `onStart()` as

   ```
   @Override
   public void onStart() {
       super.onStart();
       new BackgroundDataLoad().execute();
   }
   ```

now you loading task will perform after dialog create, so now you can look at the progress dialog is showing.

Comment: @Arthur Korchagin, Thanks for make perfection , Also if this really helpful then give up vote.

Answer (score 3):

**Simple Solution to bring ProgressDialog on front in DialogFragment**

just paste that code in your dialog fragment and it will not affect your exist code

```
   @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (pDialog.isShowing() && pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();            //dirty fix for bring progress dialog front
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and the root of the problem is that you are creating a progressDialog inside a dialogFragment. What you should do is to create a progress dialog and pass it as dialog reference in onCreateDialog in DialogFragment.

Something like:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

private ProgressDialog mProgress;

    public static JoinContactLoaderFragment newInstance() {
        JoinContactLoaderFragment fragment = new JoinContactLoaderFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mProgress.setMessage("Some text");
        mProgress.setCancelable(true);
        mProgress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        return mProgress;
    }
}
```